# CKEditor button to add table rows

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm trying to make an add button (NOT a toolbar button), so when you click on it, a new row is added to the bottom of an already existing table.

Any idea how to do this? Should it just be a button that calls a add-row-function or should it be added to the table plugin (not sure how to add it to the plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the 'tabletools' plugin and you'll have this feature for free. You only need to right-click on a table row.

[image: Add row to table]

http://ckeditor.com/addon/tabletools